# 1:1 NAT through VM VPN

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I've got a few client servers that I connect to with different VPN clients (e.g. Cisco, OpenVPN, etc). I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu 14 VM (with VPN client permanently connected) for each server to route all traffic to and from the server, so I don't need to keep switching between various VPN clients.

The VM has `eth0` with two static IPs (bridged to LAN), and I'd like to route all traffic directed to the static ip `10.1.1.200` through `tun0` to the remote server `10.50.1.1`.

I've set up the following `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.200 -j SNAT --to-source 10.50.1.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.50.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.200
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.50.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.1.1.200 -j ACCEPT
```

My understanding of this is that it creates a 1:1 NAT between the LAN IP (`10.1.1.200`) and the remote server's IP (via the OpenVPN connection) (`10.50.1.1`). I've enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, and I can connect to the host server from the VM fine.

I've tried pinging, telnetting, and sshing from the host machine to `10.1.1.200`, but I get connection refused.

I've tried a few different permutations of source/destination IPs (and explicitly setting interfaces with `-i` and `-o`), but nothing works. :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Ended up using the following, mapping the entire LAN IP range to the destination server IP range, for clients with multiple servers in the same subnet. Using masquerade so that the packet gets back to the right LAN IP.

```
iptables -v -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 10.50.1.0/24
iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```